# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'isPendingOvrd' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-dialog

There are similar type of question already asked. but none of them answers my problem. Cloud you please help me find the issue with my code.
I am calling a dialog popup for a view and a value is passed in the query string as shown below in the code.

```
function openVendTubeBalPopup(popupurl)     {                
    if (!dlgVendPop) {       
        dlgVendPop = $('#VendTubeDialog').dialog({       
                show: { clip: "blind", duration: 500 },        
                dialogClass: "myPopup",       
                height: 650,       
                width: 600,       
                modal: true,       
            resizable: false,       
            autoOpen: false       
    });           
}            
var PendingChangeOvrdDtls = true;     
$('#VendTubeDialog').load(popupurl + "?isEditMode=true" + "&isPendingOvrd=" + PendingChangeOvrdDtls );        
dlgVendPop.dialog('open');
```

}

Controller:

```
public ActionResult VendTubeBal(bool isPendingOvrd)    
{   
      SafeBalancingBiz biz = new SafeBalancingBiz(model, model.Store, model.BusinessDate, log, model.User);   
      biz.GetVendingTube();    
      return View(model.VendingTubeModel);   
}
```

the parameter 'isPendingOvrd' always contains a value but still i go that error and only once... after that all good.

Comment: This code looks fine to me.

Comment: Can there be any browser issues?? coz this error was thrown only once, i didn't see this error again.